# RxJava - retry with the same subscribeOn and scheduleOn schedulers?

Tags: rx-java

I have the following code:

```
Observable<Result> observable = ...; // result of HTTP request -> Retrofit2

observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
          .map(... do some mapping ...)
```

I use "io" scheduler to perform costly HTTP request and "computation" scheduler to execute the remaining in-memory mappings etc.

Now, I would like to add some retry functionality in case of some specific error codes, which is easy. What I don't know is how to execute this another retry HTTP request on the same "io" scheduler.

Any hints?

Comment: io() already caches and reuses threads, why do you want to go back to the same exact thread?

Comment: Not same thread, same scheduler. By default all retries are executed on trampoline scheduler.

Comment: That subscribeOn should move it back to the io() scheduler. Do you experience something different?